# How to add numbers to integer?

Tags: java, string, swing, numbers, actionlistener

Button must add 50 to integer but its not .  I dont know well about Jframe so help me guys.

```
    int money = 0;
    ...
    JButton verlan = new JButton("50 kr\u015F");
    verlan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int moremoney = money + 50;
        String x=Integer.toString(moremoney);
        textArea.setText(x + " cent");

        }
    });
```

Comment: @sam That, and how is he accessing `money` from inside his `ActionListener` without it being `final`?

Comment: @TrippKinetics Yeah. I didn't even look at that part. All I saw was numbers   :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ActionListener` you define a new variable on which you add up the value of `money` and 50, however you never update the initial value of `money`. Instead you can update money, however you have to make sure that the variable is available in the scope of the `ActionListener`, e.g. by declaring it as a member variable.

```
private int money = 0;
    ...
    JButton verlan = new JButton("50 kr\u015F");
    verlan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        money += 50;
        String x=Integer.toString(money);
        textArea.setText(x + " cent");

        }
    });
```